# Are java bean oids predictable?

Tags: java, tomcat

For example, I'm facing bean names such as "<3 CHAR PREFIX>" ex. "FIL000000AZB3Y" (random name) where FIL refers to a File object, and the 0000... is the OID. Is it possible to predict this, or is prediction only possible through bruteforcing every a-zA-Z0-9 for 5 chars.